# Exclude items from training set data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have my data in two `colors` and `excluded_colors`.

`colors` contains all colors
`excluded_colors` contains some colors that I wish to exclude from my trainingset.

I am trying to split the data into a training and testing set and ensure that the colors in `excluded_colors` are not in my training set but exist in the testing set.

In order to achieve the above, I did this

```
var colors = spark.sql("""
   select colors.* 
   from colors 
   LEFT JOIN excluded_colors 
   ON excluded_colors.color_id = colors.color_id
   where excluded_colors.color_id IS NULL
"""
)
val trainer: (Int => Int) = (arg:Int) => 0
val sqlTrainer = udf(trainer)
val tester: (Int => Int) = (arg:Int) => 1
val sqlTester = udf(tester)

val rsplit = colors.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))  
val train_colors = splits(0).select("color_id").withColumn("test",sqlTrainer(col("color_id")))
val test_colors = splits(1).select("color_id").withColumn("test",sqlTester(col("color_id")))
```

However, I'm realizing that by doing the above the colors in `excluded_colors` are completely ignored. They are not even in my testing set.

**Question**
How can I split the data in 70/30 while also ensuring that the colors in `excluded_colors` are not in training but are present in testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we want to do is remove the "excluded colors" from the training set but have them in the testing and have a training/test split of 70/30.

What we need is a bit of math.

Given the total dataset (TD) and the excluded colors dataset (E) we can say that for train dataset (Tr) and test dataset (Ts) that:

```
|Tr| = x * (|TD|-|E|)
|Ts| = |E| + (1-x) * |TD|
```

We also know that `|Tr| = 0.7 |TD|`

Hence `x = 0.7 |TD| / (|TD| - |E|)`

Now that we know the sampling factor `x`, we can say:

```
Tr = (TD-E).sample(withReplacement = false, fraction = x)
// where (TD - E) is the result of the SQL expr above

Ts = TD.sample(withReplacement = false, fraction = 0.3)
// we sample the test set from the original dataset
```

Comment: What is `x` in your example?

Comment: `x` is the sampling probability, like `0.7` or `0.3` in your question. The idea is that you need a larger sample from the smaller dataset in order to preserve the 70/30 ratio as asked in the question.

Comment: ok, I think I understand. I am going to convert your math to code and see if I'm successful at that. I'll update the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: the multiplication with `TD` doesn't work. This is what I have. `scala> TD.count res54: Long = 46520   scala> E.count  res55: Long = 41868   scala> val x = 0.7 * TD <console>:55: error: overloaded method value * with alternatives:
`

Comment: following above, `|TD|` is `totalDataset.count()` and `|E|` is `excluded_colors.count()`. So, having `val totalDatasetCount = totalDataset.count()` and `val exclColorsCount =  excluded_colors.count()`, we should be able to calculate `val adjustedSamplingFactor = 0.7d *  totalDatasetCount / (totalDatasetCount -  exclColorsCount)`

Comment: I am still not able to see a particular data that I know exists in excluded in the testing set. I still don't see it in either training or testing. please see this gist. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2b0154c2dc34e37166c36b4ae6635f3

Comment: > adjustedSamplingFactor: Double = 6.999999999999999

That doesn't seem right. It should be <1. `Excluded` should be the elements *not* wanted in the training set, there it seems to be the opposite.

Comment: You can also try splitting the filtered selection and adding the excluded elements to the test dataset. Like `val (train,partialTest) = colors.randomSplit(Array(x, 1-x))` and then `val test = partialTest.unionAll(excluded)  (where x is the factor calculated above ~= 0.7811 using the dataset count numbers found in the gist)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128204/discussion-between-anthony-and-maasg).

Comment: Yes, it worked. I ended up creating another temp table for excluded and did everything in sql.